# Delete elements in one array by using indices of second array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, splice

1) take an array `a = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j];` //actual array through JavaScript

2) take input array `'b'` of 5 numbers through html tags//b array

3) input elements of `'b'` such that they should be always less be than length of `'a'` array.

4) now delete all values from `'a'` which have index values of `'b'`

5) Now print the new `'a'` array.

1. example: `a=[23,45,5,6,3,3,5,8,97,10]`
2. take `b=[3,4,6,7,2]`
3. `new a array=[23,3,97,10,8,9]`
4. Now all those elements in array one got deleted b's elements.
5. `a[3],a[4],a[6],a[7],a[2]` got deleted (do not disturb the array index).

Comment: Why is `5` in resulting array?

Comment: @guest271314 ya I was supposed to remove it. now its fine

Comment: May we see an attempt from you, OP? This looks like a request for free work.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Question in English are denoted by a question-mark, ?,  and can receive an answer. As is, this post is a pure homework dump. Please read up on [ask] on this site, and also on [what topics you can ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: why is `9` in the result set? why comes `10` before `8`? why do you get 6 items if you delete from 10 items 5?

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` instead

```
a = a.filter( function(item, index){ //iterate the array a
  return b.indexOf(index+1) == -1; //removing those items whose index is not in the index array b. index-array b has 1-based indexes as per your example
});
```